# Object not found error. How it can be solved?

Tags: excel, vba

This code is producing an "Object not found" error.

```
Sub Button86_Click()
    Dim Y As Integer
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim LastRow As Long

    Y = 2
    Worksheets("Abnormal").Activate

    With ActiveSheet
        LastRow = .Range("A1").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row
    End With

    Sheets("Abnormal").Rows(1).Copy Destination:=Sheets("Ab_IT").Rows(1)
    For i = 2 To LastRow
        If Abnormal.Cells(i, 11).Value = "IT" Then
            Sheets("Abnormal").Rows(i).Copy Destination:=Sheets("Ab_IT").Rows(Y)
            Y = Y + 1  
        End If
    Next i

    Worksheets("Ab_IT").Activate

    With ActiveSheet.UsedRange
        .Cells.Copy
        .Cells.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
        .Cells(1).Select
    End With

    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Worksheets("Ab_IT").Columns("A:J").AutoFit
End Sub
```

** Error line - If Abnormal.Cells(i, 11).Value = "IT" Then
Details - There are two sheets. Abnormal and Ab_IT.
In Abnormal sheet, there is one column(11),which sometimes contain "IT"
I am trying to copy all the rows, which contain IT to another sheet Ab_IT.
But getting an error object not defined.

Comment: Try to add more details to your question, you might get a better response.

Comment: What line produces the error.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see the variable 'Abnormal' defined prior to this line:

```
If Abnormal.Cells(i, 11).Value = "IT" Then
```

Maybe you meant:

```
If Sheets("Abnormal").Cells(i, 11).Value = "IT" Then
```